# Customizing plays fbconnect module

Tags: facebook, playframework

When i'm trying to log in to facebook with button from fbconnect module, I am getting nullpointer at this line:

```
String email = data.get("email").getAsString();
```

where data is JsonObject. So I checked this json response from facebook, and found that has many data, but email isn't included.

I suppose i have to change something in fbconnect module, like change request, to get more data from facebook, can somebody tell me where and how ?

Im talking about play framework ofc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `email` extended permission to access the email field for a user - ensure you have this by calling `/me/permissions` with your access token - it'll show you the permissions your access token has

Answer (score 1):

Add the email scope tag to your fbconnect button:

```
#{fbconnect.button label:'Login using your facebook account.', scope:'email'/}
```